# Is there any way to run a flutter windows app on mac?

Tags: flutter, macos, android-studio, dart

I've enabled the support for windows-desktop on flutter... but is there any way to compile and run the windows flutter app on macOS?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As of now! Unfortunately, "build windows" is only supported on Windows hosts.

However, you can have have virtual tools to help you build on Mac for example

**[Apple Boot Camp](https://support.apple.com/HT201468)**
The Boot Camp Assistant app is pre-installed on every recent Mac, and launching it will walk you through the process of installing Windows 10.

**[Parallels Desktop](https://www.parallels.com/download/desktop/)**
Using Parallels Desktop 11, you can run Windows apps side-by-side with existing Mac applications, including Visual Studio and Cortana.

**[VMWare Fusion](http://www.vmware.com/products/fusion/)**
Fusion 8 from VMWare will let you run Visual Studio right on your Mac desktop.

**[Oracle VirtualBox](https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Downloads)**
VirtualBox is a free application for running virtual machines on your computer, and it supports running Windows on Mac.

Once you have these tools, you can install windows and start developing on Windows but virtually through Mac host.

Comment: Thank you! I found this page on Reddit to have some good info comparing boot camp with parallels: https://www.reddit.com/r/macbookair/comments/m5q653/bootcamp_or_parallels_which_one_is_more_stable/